# Как сделать захват области окна на С++/NodeJs как в OBS?

Tags: c++, node.js, ffmpeg

Как можно сделать захват окна в реальном времени, так же как это работает в программе OBS на предпросмотре, там полностью отсутствует задержка. Я пробовал это сделать через ffmpeg под управлением NodeJs

```
ffmpeg -re -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -probesize 32 -offset_x 1000 -offset_y 300 -draw_mouse 0 -video_size 600x240 -i title=TestStopwatch -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live
```

Но у меня задержка на 1 сек, так и не получилось сделать ее меньше, может есть другой способ реализовать это на C++ например, либо как то можно сделать это через тот же ffmpeg? Пишу простенькую программу для определения по небольшой области экрана, действие которое нужно совершить с минимальной задержкой.